# Can't create project with Google Map android API V2

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I have read document in 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start
I create project android in eclipse, folow document step by step but when I can't run project.

sample error java.lang.NullPointerException

error log

```
03-20 15:13:39.332: D/AndroidRuntime(28930): Shutting down VM
03-20 15:13:39.332: W/dalvikvm(28930): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x2b542210)
03-20 15:13:39.352: E/AndroidRuntime(28930): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-20 15:13:39.352: E/AndroidRuntime(28930): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.my_ap/com.mrbuoi.my_ap.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-20 15:13:39.352: E/AndroidRuntime(28930):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1967)
03-20 15:13:39.352: E/AndroidRuntime(28930):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1992)
03-20 15:13:39.352: E/AndroidRuntime(28930):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
03-20 15:13:39.352: E/AndroidRuntime(28930):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1158)
03-20 15:13:39.352: E/AndroidRuntime(28930):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-20 15:13:39.352: E/AndroidRuntime(28930):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-20 15:13:39.352: E/AndroidRuntime(28930):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4441)
03-20 15:13:39.352: E/AndroidRuntime(28930):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-20 15:13:39.352: E/AndroidRuntime(28930):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-20 15:13:39.352: E/AndroidRuntime(28930):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
03-20 15:13:39.352: E/AndroidRuntime(28930):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:565)
03-20 15:13:39.352: E/AndroidRuntime(28930):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-20 15:13:39.352: E/AndroidRuntime(28930): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-20 15:13:39.352: E/AndroidRuntime(28930):    at com.mrbuoi.my_ap.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:31)
03-20 15:13:39.352: E/AndroidRuntime(28930):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
03-20 15:13:39.352: E/AndroidRuntime(28930):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
03-20 15:13:39.352: E/AndroidRuntime(28930):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1931)
03-20 15:13:39.352: E/AndroidRuntime(28930):    ... 11 more
```

----- File AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.my_ap"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="14" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<!-- The following two permissions are not required to use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="15" />
    <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="MY_APIKEY"/>
    <activity
        android:name="com.mrbuoi.may_ap.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

---- File MainActivity.java

```
package com.mrbuoi.my_ap;

import com.example.my_ap.R;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.*;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.*;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.os.Build;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     GoogleMap map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-33.867, 151.206);

        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(sydney, 13));

        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .title("Sydney")
                .snippet("The most populous city in Australia.")
                .position(sydney));
}
}
```

----- File  Fragment_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.mrbuoi.my_ap.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

<fragment
      android:id="@+id/map"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Update activity_main.xml**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.mrbuoi.bactai_app.MainActivity"
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />
```

Anyone got a tip? Tks

---

**UPDATE:**
@PiYusH GuPtA, I have try this but this not work.
my Error log

```
03-20 15:24:42.922: E/AndroidRuntime(29491): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-20 15:24:42.922: E/AndroidRuntime(29491): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.my_ap/com.mrbuoi.my_ap.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-20 15:24:42.922: E/AndroidRuntime(29491):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1967)
03-20 15:24:42.922: E/AndroidRuntime(29491):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1992)
03-20 15:24:42.922: E/AndroidRuntime(29491):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
03-20 15:24:42.922: E/AndroidRuntime(29491):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1158)
03-20 15:24:42.922: E/AndroidRuntime(29491):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-20 15:24:42.922: E/AndroidRuntime(29491):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-20 15:24:42.922: E/AndroidRuntime(29491):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4441)
03-20 15:24:42.922: E/AndroidRuntime(29491):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-20 15:24:42.922: E/AndroidRuntime(29491):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-20 15:24:42.922: E/AndroidRuntime(29491):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
03-20 15:24:42.922: E/AndroidRuntime(29491):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:565)
03-20 15:24:42.922: E/AndroidRuntime(29491):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-20 15:24:42.922: E/AndroidRuntime(29491): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-20 15:24:42.922: E/AndroidRuntime(29491):    at com.mrbuoi.my_ap.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:22)
03-20 15:24:42.922: E/AndroidRuntime(29491):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
03-20 15:24:42.922: E/AndroidRuntime(29491):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
03-20 15:24:42.922: E/AndroidRuntime(29491):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1931)
03-20 15:24:42.922: E/AndroidRuntime(29491):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: post your code and the stacktrace

Comment: Can you paste the error log with question ?

Comment: you first make sure which layout belong your MapFragment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to change your `Activity` to `FragmentActivity` while extending in your class as below:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity{
```

And also your layout inflating which contains the `GoogleMap` view is having name `Fragment_main` and in your activity you have inflated the layout `activity_main` which is wrong.

So change your `setContentView` layout

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

to

```
setContentView(R.layout.Fragment_main);
```

Also as you are having the minimum api level below 11 so you have to use `SupportMapFragment` to load the map as below:

```
  GoogleMap map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

**EDITED:**

In your manifest change your below line

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="15" />
```

to

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Also change your `Fragment` class name as below in your `fragment_main` layout file.

```
<fragment
      android:id="@+id/map"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

Comment: What is the problem you are facing ? @PhantuHydro Have you done all the changes which i have mentioned in my answer ?

Comment: I have used this but not work

when I create project android, eclipse auto create fragment_main.xml
I have used code setContentView(R.layout.Fragment_main); program not work. I changed to setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);,
program has worked. and then I added code
map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
program not work again :( ...

Comment: Check my answer again

Comment: @PhantuHydro Have your changed your `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` to `setContentView(R.layout.Fragment_main);`

Comment: H have used 2 answer it will work true :) ... 
1 of you and 
1 of bottom answer. that why I ratting for 2 answer :) ...

Answer (score 1):

you need to extends your class a ***FragmentActivity*** instead of ***Activity***.

Other thing that you have to add

```
  <uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />
```

in your manifest file.

Also change this

```
  if(map!=null){

   LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-33.867, 151.206);

   map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
   map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(sydney, 13));

   map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .title("Sydney")
            .snippet("The most populous city in Australia.")
            .position(sydney));

  }
```

***UPDATE:***

change here from

```
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

to

```
  setContentView(R.layout.Fragment_main);
```

Use this

```
  <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.mrbuoi.bactai_app.MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

    <include layout="@layout/Fragment_main"></include>
  </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: I have used this but not work

when I create project android, eclipse auto create fragment_main.xml
I have used code setContentView(R.layout.Fragment_main); program not work. I changed to setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);,
program has worked. and then I added code
map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
program not work again :( ...

Comment: Do one thing paste your code of Fragment_main.xml to activity_main.xml file and it will be worked