# GoogleMap Crashes android Java android 4.3

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-maps

i have to show google map in android EMulator,but its crashes,even every time when i download code for google map,i place may api key,all others libraries but Apps Crash,this is my current code.

```
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    GoogleMap map;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);

        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(13.05241, 80.25082);
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("Raj Amal"));
    }}
```

but app crashes when  `map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);` and below is my log cat

```
    03-21 07:24:33.904: E/AndroidRuntime(1039): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    03-21 07:24:33.904: E/AndroidRuntime(1039): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.amal.googlemap/com.amal.googlemap.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    03-21 07:24:33.904: E/AndroidRuntime(1039):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
    03-21 07:24:33.904: E/AndroidRuntime(1039):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
    03-21 07:24:33.904: E/AndroidRuntime(1039):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
    03-21 07:24:33.904: E/AndroidRuntime(1039):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
    03-21 07:24:33.904: E/AndroidRuntime(1039):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    03-21 07:24:33.904: E/AndroidRuntime(1039):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    03-21 07:24:33.904: E/AndroidRuntime(1039):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
    03-21 07:24:33.904: E/AndroidRuntime(1039):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    03-21 07:24:33.904: E/AndroidRuntime(1039):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
    03-21 07:24:33.904: E/AndroidRuntime(1039):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
    03-21 07:24:33.904: E/AndroidRuntime(1039):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
    03-21 07:24:33.904: E/AndroidRuntime(1039):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    03-21 07:24:33.904: E/AndroidRuntime(1039): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    03-21 07:24:33.904: E/AndroidRuntime(1039):     at com.amal.googlemap.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:18)
    03-21 07:24:33.904: E/AndroidRuntime(1039):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
    03-21 07:24:33.904: E/AndroidRuntime(1039):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
    03-21 07:24:33.904: E/AndroidRuntime(1039):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
    03-21 07:24:33.904: E/AndroidRuntime(1039):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Try this `map.setMapType(MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);` instead of `map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);`

Comment: error MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE cannot be resolved to a variable

Comment: map is null. also check the availability of google play services before initializing GoogleMap object

Comment: any verified tutorial for google map with lat/lng

Comment: google map will not work in Emulator you will have make changes in your emulator config to run google map in it. search on google.

Comment: @Bilals... Check out the similar thread http://stackoverflow.com/a/22527848/1839336

Comment: @GrIsHu comments shows your reference link to resolved

Comment: @Bilals... That question is similar to your issue. You might get some idea about your issue. My Answer will help you also.

Comment: @Bilals... Did that thread help ??

Answer (score 1):

You should implement like this

```
int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil
            .isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(youractivity.this);

    if (status == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {

        setUpMapIfNeeded();

    } else {
        int requestCode = 10;
        Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, youractivity.this,
                requestCode);
        dialog.show();
    }
```

For setup **Google Play Services Lib** go to [official docs](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html)

Comment: is Google play services and my application android version should be same?

Comment: @Bilals... no men. go to this [http://www.vardhan-ds.co.in/2013/11/android-mapfragmentgetmap-returns-null.html](http://www.vardhan-ds.co.in/2013/11/android-mapfragmentgetmap-returns-null.html)

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to show the google map in Emulator, you have to create avd without google api and install  Google_Play_services_4.0.31.apk and com.android.vending.apk(google play store) and then run your application

[image]

let me know if any issue, and select my answer if its working fine